# Can an exploding object survive?

Tags: science-based, science-fiction, explosions

Imagine a small object (a sphere in my mind) buried underground. This object is meant to cause some vibrations around and then take some measurements.
In order to cause the vibrations, I see no option other than making it cause an explosion.
Is it possible for an object to cause a (small) explosion and remain undamaged?

The setting is a scientifically and technologically advanced civilization. No magic.

Comment: The explosive device could just be set away from the main body of the device connected by small support. You could have multiple devices protruding in different directions if you need multiple charges. You could also fire charges like a gun, but you probably should shape the hole so that the projectile doesn't impact right at the muzzle and somewhere a little away from the main body

Comment: There are plenty of reusable explosives or things that similarly produce energy outwards. You probably need to "recharge" them like adding another firework, or arm them again in another fashion but that's not at all uncommon in our real world right now.

Comment: How big of an explosive? how much vibrations are you hoping to achieve? How sensitive is your measuring device? Can the explosion occur remote to the sensor? (which is more useful to measure vibrations than having the sensor at the point of explosion.)

Comment: EMP explosion maybe? Or are you looking for proper conventional boom-booms?

Comment: Firearms cause a small explosion and remain undamaged.  Is there any particular reason you're worried your devices may not be able to do similar?

Comment: "In order to cause the vibrations I see no other option that making it cause an explosion.": uh...why? There are many, many ways of producing vibrations that don't involve exploding.

Comment: To further extend ChristopherJamesHuff's surprise, you might learn a thing or two with [ground-penetrating radars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ground-penetrating_radar) and perhaps [core samples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_sample), too. But if explosives is what you want, let's explode our cold reality for TNT !

Comment: Note : If you use conventional explosives, remember that explosive charges are generally one-time use only. Not necessarily because it... Well, explodes everything, but just because the chemicals producing the explosion has reacted and cannot go back. If you plan on making several measurements (a staple of scientific studies), you'll probably have to stock up on TNT charges and eventually reload your device(s) ^^.

Comment: Note that bats and dolphins accomplish the same thing via echolocation, whereby they sense their surroundings by emitting sonic vibrations and measuring the reflections. Obviously, they don't explode to do this.

Answer (score 12):

### Frame Challenge: You don't need explosions at all

> This object is meant to cause some vibrations around and then take some measurements

What you are basically describing sounds like a seismic sensor system that makes its own waves... but such things exist that are sensitive enough that you don't need anything as dramatic as an explosion.  They use soundwaves in a fashion similar to echo location.  Such devices can already be used by geologists to map out underground structures in pretty good detail.  So instead of an explosion, you just need a powerful speaker system.

Comment: True, sounds are vibrations.

Comment: Or drop a weight (maybe inside the object). https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vxfJbW6KDp4 something like this but inside a huge cylinder, making it one object that's buried. Of course the measuring electronics would need to be able to withstand the vibrations as well but that's within current engineering, just gonna be a bit more expensive

Comment: Tesla actually designed an engine that had the problem of causing vibrations https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l5rEW9QgJDc

Comment: My washing machine causes some major vibrations everyday. Still waiting for it to explode.

Answer (score 9):

## Touch your Dingaling

[image]

Sound is a type of vibration. To make vibrations, your device makes a sound. Since we're talking about a metal sphere, I suggest the outer surface works like a bicycle bell. There is a little hammer that strikes the shell and makes a ding ding noise.

Comment: +1 There is just no competing with a tagline like that. LOL.

Comment: Are you sure it's a good idea to answer now? 3 close votes about lack of clarity. We aren't even sure of the power needed of the measurements, like it could be some kind of extremely absorbant ground a big bell can't go through.

Comment: @Nosajimiki [This act is over!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DMuTvoD1QNs)

Answer (score 5):

Million of people every day have a little device buried inside them which causes vibrations and then take some measurements.

No, none of those million people is damaged or killed by an explosion: that device is a smartphone set on vibrate mode, and it is buried in the pocket of their clothes.

[image]

Your assumption that

> In order to cause the vibrations, I see no option other than making it cause an explosion

is simply wrong. You just need displacing a mass quick enough and the reaction (good old third Newton law) will cause a vibration. Just look at yourself in the mirror while shaking a bottle of juice.

Answer (score 3):

*Is it possible for something to set off a small explosion without being damaged?* That's what a gun does. You just don't need the barrel. You can even use shaped charges so that the blast wave mostly travels in one direction.

This is a technique called "Deep seismic sounding." On Earth, we don't need a device to make the explosions. The crust is like a million creaky doors, and we can use the "noise" of earthquakes and tremors, bouncing off of the density gradients, to tell what our crust and mantle look like.

Comment: A gun is not an exploding object. A bullet is an exploding object. And a bullet is quite destroyed in the process.

Comment: @virolino, In the body of the question he clarifies that he's looking for something that causes an explosion.

Answer (score 3):

## A car engine.

Almost any car engine would suffice. If you must have explosions, a combustion chamber creates explosions without destroying itself (most of the time). You might want an older engine if you want multiple smaller vibrations or a newer engine for stability. Maybe have the crankshaft press against a spring, which pushes a cut-out part of the casing outwards if you don't want to handle the rotational movement a normal engine creates.

Comment: Now that is a very original POV! :) However, the engine is not exploding - it is just a chamber where the exploding happens. Also however, it would work perfectly in the setup described by OP - especially if combined with an eccentric like the vibration motors in smartphones. +1

Answer (score 0):

Ocean waves are strong enough to go many hundreds of kilometers into the continent where sensitive seismic recorders can pick them. While really strong earthquakes are rare, weak earthquakes possible to pick very far away from where originated would also come at rarest every few days. Hence if the device is as sensitive as modern seismometer, there is no need to test it with explosion.